# Using <a href""> instead of click/touch/pointer event

Tags: javascript, touch, href

I've been struggling for a while making websites compatible for desktop, tablet and mobile at once. There are loads of libraries to handle *pointer events* on touch devices. One of them is [hand.js](https://handjs.codeplex.com/), which combines mouse and touch in pointer events, without me having to consider what device it is used for. Hand.js is working superb, exept for one problem. On touch devices, a *pointerdown* event is triggered even if it is intended as the start of a scroll or pinch.

There are solutions to work around this, but instead of adding more and more javascript, I considered ditching all libraries for touch and let the browser decide for itself.

To accomplish this, I'm thinking of using (or abusing :-) the `<a href"">` tag.

Instead of (for simplicity I use onclick inline instead of add an eventlistener) using:

```
<div class="myclass" onclick="start(1,2,3)">Hello</div>
```

I could use

```
<a href='javascript:{start(1,2,3);void(0);}'><div class="myclass">Hello</div></a>
```

The benefit of this solution would be:

- the device browser decides how to handle the click/touch, whilst zooming and scrolling is still enabled without triggering any unwanted action.
- there is no need to register any event to the button.
- I don't need any library

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k9ezyubo/1/) and (to my surprise) it is working. However, I'm no expert, hence my question:

**Can I use this method without running into problems?**